# Needed help in Selecting the earliest Date from the dataframe in R

Tags: r, date, dataset, logic

I have set of data similar to this and wanted to get the earliest date of the SORT_DT when values of all the different columns match. Please help me solve this issue

```
df <- fread("CUST_NO ID_NO SYMBOL  AUTO_CREATE_DT     CLASS_TYPE    SORT_DT
         107   10120      1    2014-05-12             G/L  2015-01-09
        107   10120      1    2014-05-12             G/L  2015-11-10
        107   10120      1    2014-05-12             G/L  2014-06-18
        107   10120      1    2014-05-12             G/L  2014-05-13
        107   10120      1    2014-05-12             G/L  2015-07-10
        107   10120      1    2014-05-12             G/L  2015-10-09
        107   10120      1    2014-05-12             G/L  2016-04-08
        107   10120      1    2014-05-12             G/L  2016-01-08
        107   10120      1    2014-05-12             G/L  2016-12-22
        107   10120      1    2014-05-12             G/L  2017-01-13
        107   10120      1    2014-05-12             G/L  2016-07-08
        108   10120      1    2014-05-12             G/L  2017-04-14
        108   10120      1    2014-05-12             G/L  2017-04-17
        108   10120      1    2014-05-12             G/L  2016-08-31
        108   10120      1    2014-05-12             G/L  2015-04-10
        108   10120      1    2014-05-12             G/L  2016-12-22")
```

The output should be as below

```
  CUST_NO   ID_NO      SYMBOL  AUTO_CREATE_DT     CLASS_TYPE    SORT_DT
1         107     10120      1    2014-05-12             G/L     2014-05-13
2         108     10120      1    2014-05-12             G/L     2015-04-10
```

Comment: Consider reviewing the following SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33436647/group-by-and-select-min-date-with-data-table. Your syntax would be as follows: `setDT(df)[, .SD[which.min(as.Date(SORT_DT))], by = CUST_NO]`

Comment: @ccapizzano Thank you for your response. As my data set is large and did put only part of it due to security concerns can you please let me know  how can I solve this question if all the rows  of CUST_NO  ID_NO  SYMBOL  AUTO_CREATE_DT    CLASS_TYPE matches then selecting earliest date from SORT_DT

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    df2 <- aggregate(df, list(df$CUST_NO, df$ID_NO, df$SYMBOL, df$AUTO_CREATE_DT, df$CLASS_TYPE), FUN = min)
    df2 <- df2[c("CUST_NO", "ID_NO", "SYMBOL", "AUTO_CREATE_DT", "CLASS_TYPE", "SORT_DT")]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
aggregate(SORT_DT ~ ., data = df, min)

#   CUST_NO ID_NO SYMBOL AUTO_CREATE_DT CLASS_TYPE    SORT_DT
# 1     107 10120      1     2014-05-12        G/L 2014-05-13
# 2     108 10120      1     2014-05-12        G/L 2015-04-10
```